JavaScript Fullscreen: fullscreenEnabled is always false and fullscreenElement is not the element requested on
There is a [Lit] WebComponent that I call requestFullscreen() on (this.requestFullscreen()). It's a toggle, so when the same action is clicked again I check for if (document.fullscreenElement === this), since this is the element that requested fullscreen.
However, document.fullscreenElement is actually the next highest ancestor WebComponent, not even any of the native HTML ancestors between these two WebComponents. So I decided to use document.fullscreenEnabled, just to see if it was and toggle fullscreen off. Turns out, document.fullscreenEnabled is always false.
For now my workaround, because document.fullscreenElement is either that ancestor or null, I am just checking if (!!document.fullscreenElement). This is kinda kludgy, IMO, but works.
Why is document.fullscreenEnabled always false and document.fullscreenElement not this when I called this.requestFullscreen() to invoke fullscreen?

Please create a [mcve] if possible. Perhaps using JSFiddle if SO does not allow it

Starting with fullscreenEnabled, it doesn't indicate if user is in full screen mode, it only  indicates ability for browser to requestFullscreen, can read more in MDN docs
If you want to check if user is in full screen, you are doing correct thing by checking fullscreenElement, because bool indicator for fullscreen is depercated
But when it comes to document.fullscreenElement not being equal to your web component, it really depends on your or library's implementation, common mistake could be not awaiting Promise returned by requestFullscreen, in basic setup it works as expected, e.g.
await document.body.requestFullscreen();
console.log(document.fullscreenElement === document.body); // Will print true


thank you for the clarity. I am half tempted to chalk it up to a browser bug because, for whatever reason, after I await the call to requestFullscreen and check document.fullscreenElement it is always the ancestor mentioned in the OP. It is peculiar, too, because: it's not, say, the immediate parentElement that is the document.fullscreenElement; it's not even something closer to the root of the DOM; it's this very particular element that is the next highest Shadow Root. It is so straight-forward what I am doing that I wouldn't even know what else to try.

If you are using it with compatible elements, I would assume it's designed this way, however I found that there is fullscreenElement in shadow root as well, you could try something like this.renderRoot.fullscreenElement however I didn't verify it, but it should work accodrding to docs:
https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#accessing-nodes-in-the-shadow-dom
https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/ (Need to search for shadowRoot)

Method does not exist on this.renderRoot :( I also tried it with this.shadowRoot and same result. Thank you for the suggestion tho -- I am open to anything here.
